# rails use scaffold generated api to change object's property

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated with scaffold Item:
`rails generate scaffold item detail:integer`

How do I make an ajax request that will  take item that has `id=n`  and  set `detail=1`

Comment: please make comment why you downvote this.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to do an ajax request in rails.
Rails has an excellent documentation about how javascript works with him: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Just as an example, using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
 $.put('/items/1.json', $('#your-form').serialize() )
```

Comment: How should my `$('#your-form') ` look like?

Comment: And I don't need server method do handle this? scaffold already built it?